# Query with LINQ working only during debugging

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

I've been trying to request the property "CNPJ" with a POST and I'm getting the following error:

```
 "[IBM][IDS/UNIX64] Column (id_contrato2) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined)."
```

RepService.cs

```cs
public IEnumerable<entidade.shared.Representante> GetRepresentantes(Expression<Func<Representantecontrato, bool>> whereClause, int limit)
{
    var representantecontratos = Context.GetEntitySet<Representantecontrato>().Query().ConditionalWhere(whereClause);
    var listaPapeis = new List<string> { CodFuncoes.AC.Nome(), CodFuncoes.NC.Nome(), CodFuncoes.TC.Nome() };
 
    var query = (from representantecontrato in representantecontratos
                select new entidade.shared.Representante
                {
                    Papel = representantecontrato.DescricaoFuncao,
                    Cpf = representantecontrato.DescricaoCpf,
                    Cnpj = representantecontrato.Contrato.AgenteconcessaoLista.FirstOrDefault().NuCnpj,
                    Email = representantecontrato.DescricaoEmail,
                    Nome = representantecontrato.DescricaoNome,
                    Cargo = representantecontrato.DescricaoCargo
                }).Take(limit);
 
    var listaRepresentantes = query.ToList();
 
    var results = GetPerfilRepresentante(listaRepresentantes, listaPapeis);
 
    return results;
}
```

I'm not so experienced with LINQ, so I suppose this could be a silly mistake. When I repeat a similar query during Debug, I manage to access the CNPJ value!

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you pointing at the right database? is it the same as your debug database?

Comment: Yes! It works if I remove the line: Cnpj = representantecontrato.Contrato.AgenteconcessaoLista.FirstOrDefault().NuCnpj

Comment: Are you certain that every property on the way to NuCpnj is not null? In `representantecontrato.Contrato.AgenteconcessaoLista.FirstOrDefault().NuCnpj` do you faithfully promise that Contrato and AgenteconcessaoLista are not null and the list definitely contains at least one element?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so the solution that worked out for me until now was simply to add `.ToList()` after `representantecontratos`. This idea came from a colleague, I believe it has something to do with searching the database.

```cs
public IEnumerable<entidade.shared.Representante> GetRepresentantes(Expression<Func<Representantecontrato, bool>> whereClause, int limit)
{
    var representantecontratos = Context.GetEntitySet<Representantecontrato>().Query().ConditionalWhere(whereClause);
    var listaPapeis = new List<string> { CodFuncoes.AC.Nome(), CodFuncoes.NC.Nome(), CodFuncoes.TC.Nome() };
 
    var query = (from representantecontrato in representantecontratos.ToList()
                select new entidade.shared.Representante
                {
                    Papel = representantecontrato.DescricaoFuncao,
                    Cpf = representantecontrato.DescricaoCpf,
                    Cnpj = representantecontrato.Contrato.AgenteconcessaoLista.FirstOrDefault().NuCnpj,
                    Email = representantecontrato.DescricaoEmail,
                    Nome = representantecontrato.DescricaoNome,
                    Cargo = representantecontrato.DescricaoCargo
                }).Take(limit);
 
    var listaRepresentantes = query.ToList();
 
    var results = GetPerfilRepresentante(listaRepresentantes, listaPapeis);
 
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Why is this not useful?
It solved my problem...